# Issues with div inside div height

Tags: html, css, web, height

I have an issue with the code below. If you run it you'll see that the background doesn't flow with the content, any ideas how to fix this, thanks.

All the divs are needed the **sw** is used to stop the content going bigger then 900px;
**one** and **two** are used to slit the content into two columns unless its a mobile device, i.e less then 481px;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #about {
        background-color: #ecf0f1; 
        padding: 50px; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        color: #7f8c8d;
    }

    .sw { 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        max-width: 900px;
    }

@media (min-width: 481px) {

    .one { 
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%; 
        text-align: left; 
        float: left;
    }

    .two {
        height: 100%; 
        width: 50%; 
        text-align: right; 
        float: right;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {

    .one { 
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
    }
    .two { 
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 20px;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
    }
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
      <section id="about">
    <div class="sw">
        <div class="one">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: best to provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) here.

Comment: overflow that `.sw` guy and it should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you float the contents, you need to add `overflow:auto` to the container to restore the behavior you seek:

```
.sw {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aF3jA/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a clearfix to achieve the effect you want, the float of `.one` and `.two` causes the current effect.

```
#about:before,
#about:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
}
#about:after {
  clear:both;
}
#about {
  zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

You can read more about it here http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/